# fivestar module js breaking my custom js

Tags: javascript, rating

My problem is when I use five star module on any page my js gets break on that particular page. I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: May be there are conflicts in js you are using try debugging in console, then post exact error.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED livereload.js?snipver=1
6[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector

Comment: Edit the question to include this error in it.

Comment: recently i have checked that when someone votes on any page with fivestar the js works fine i.e after ajax update it works fine. but on load first time the js breaks not all but slide toggle effect

Comment: List jquery and all other js you are using and format you qustion in something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653237/socket-io-failed-to-load-resource

Comment: Put more information ? What is written on your js ?